# Simple binding issue

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hi I am having trouble with this tutorial. I copied over the code but for some reason it is not working.

This is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<title>Simple app</title>

<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller = "MyController">
<h1>{{ person }}</h1>
and their name:
<h2> {{person.name}}</h2>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the JS

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
$scope.person = {
 name: "Ari Lerner"
    };
});
```

It doesn't look like the AngularJS code is being recognized. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app name in the module definition:

`var app = angular.module('app', []);`

doesn't match the one you reference in your dom:

`<div ng-app="myApp">`

Change your module definition to:

`var app = angular.module('myApp', []);`